# Many-to-Many Select second order

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How can I display only pc name and server name similar to my SQL query using Linq?
Table 'pc' has not navigation property for 'os'[image]

```
select pc.name, server.name
from pc 
join pc_os on pc.id = pc_os.id_pc
join os on os.id = pc_os.id_os
join os_server on os_server.id_os = os.id
join server on server.id = os_server.id_server
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties are visible. Also, show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

For better linq you need to share more code.

```
 var test = (from p in  db.pc
              join po in db.pc_os on p.id equal po.id_pc
              join o in db.os on po.id_os equal o.id
              join so in db.os_serve on o.id equal so.id_os
              join s in db.server on os.id_server equal s.id
              select new {
                    p.name,
                    s.name
              }).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a standard many-to-many relation between `Pcs` and `Osses` (plural of Os?): Every Pc has zero or more Osses, every Os is the Os on zero or more Pcs.
This many-to-many relation is implemented using a junction table.

Similarly there is a many-to-many between Osses and Servers: every Os is the Os on zero or more Servers, every Server uses zero or more Osses.

You want for every Pc name, all names of the servers that are related to this Pc.

Whenever you want "items with its zero or more sub-items", like Teachers with their  Students (many-to-many), Customers with their Orders (one-to-many), or in your case a many-to-many-to-many, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin)

If you really want a flat result, use Join instead of GroupJoin. The disadvantage is, that if a Pc has five operating systems, then GroupJoin will transfer the PC data only once, with the data of all its operating systems, while a Join will transfer the PC data five times.

To make the GroupJoin a bit readable, I'll first write a method to query PCs with their Operating Systems

```
var pcsWithTheirOperatingSystems = dbContext.Pcs.GroupJoin(dbContext.Pc_Os,

    pc => pc.Id,         // from every Pc take the primary key
    pcos => pcos.PcId,   // from the junction table, take the foreign key to the Pc

    // parameter resultSelector: from every pc with its zero or more pc_os
    // make one object
    (pc, pcossesOfThisPc) => new 
    {
        Pc = pc,

        // to get the operating systems, GroupJoin every pc_os of this PC with the 
        // operating systems
        OperatingSystems = pcossesOfThisPc.GroupJoin(dbContext.Osses,

            pcos => pcos.OsId,   // from the junction table take the foreign key                os => os.Id
            os => os.Id,         // from every Os take the primary key

            (pcos, operatingSystems) => operatingSystems)
    });
```

Similarly, you can write a method to get "Operating Systems with their Servers"

```
IQueryable<Os> operatingSystems = ...
var operatingSystemsWithTheirServers = operatingSystems.GroupJoin(dbContex.os_servers,

    operatingSystem => operatingSystem.Id,  // from ever OS take the primary key
    os_server => os_server.OsId,            // from every os_server take the foreign key

    (operatingSystem, osids) => new
    {
         OperatingSystem = operatingSystem,
         Server = osids.GroupJoin(dbContext.Servers,

             osserver => osid.ServerId,     // from every os_server take the foreign key
             server => server.Id,           // from every server take the primary key

             (osserver, servers) => servers);
```

If you put these two together, you get something like:

```
=> new
{
    Pc = {... pc properties},
    OperatingSystems = 
    { 
        OperatingSystem = {... operating system properties}

        Servers = { ... server properties}
    },
});
```

You are only interested in the names of the PCs and the Server, so you can skip the rest. Use SelectMany to get one sequence, and use Distinct to remove duplicate Server names.

```
=> new
{
    PcName = pc.Name,

    ServerNames = OperatingSystems.SelectMany(operatingSystem => Servers,
        (operatingSystem, server) => server.Name)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList(),
}
```

I could write this in one big LINQ statement, however I don't think this would make it clearer.